# stackoverflow error in kryo library in hive 2.3.2

Tags: hive, emr, kryo

I am migrating emr jobs from emr 3.7.0 to 5.13.0. We use brickhouse udf function in our hive script. On EMR 5.13.0 I am getting  *stackoverflow error in kryo library*. Upon diving deep I found out that this issue([link](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/issues/341)) was fixed into kryo library in 2015. 
I am getting following exception in hive 2.3.2.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
Serialization trace:
_tableInfo (org.codehaus.jackson.sym.BytesToNameCanonicalizer)
_rootByteSymbols (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory)
jsonFactory (brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF)
genericUDF (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc)
colExprMap (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator)
```

Followed by

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:557)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:61)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Generics.getConcreteClass(Generics.java:62)
```

This stack trace contains code([link](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/pull/342/files#diff-44fbef77d925cc9aa7459e38b5d54a23L62)) which were removed as part of fix from kryo library.

Comment: Can you please post your hive query & DDL commands of tables involved that are failing?